# After uploading a file from local file system I want to read the content of file in one variable

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to upload the file  from a  local file system to another local file system. for that I have use browse and upload button with  the url of the form from my local file system. I have written this form in html.

(index.xqy)

```
  <form name="test" action="upload.xqy?uid={xdmp:random()}" method="post" 
             enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <p><label>File to upload:
 <input type="file" class="name" name="upload" size="50"/></label></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="submit"/></p>
```

(:Upload.xqy:)

Now I want  to read the content of the file which I was  uploading the file from file system.

I have tried `get-request-body()` but it's not working. This is the flow of my requirement: After reading the file content, I will save that in local file system(D or E) with `xdmp:save()`. Can any one please help me to get the file content ?

Comment: Please do not use hashtags for keywords as you did in your title - we do have tags for that and this ain't twitter. Also, please make sure to check your spelling.

Comment: Thank you . I will make sure from next time

Answer (score 3):

You are providing a name for the field that holds the file, you can access it through the request field using that name:

```
xdmp:get-request-field("upload")
```

See also: http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:get-request-field

HTH!

Comment: Its working. But i can  take only one file at a time in upload . I want to select multiple files at a time . is there any way to select multiple files from our system and to read the content of multiple files at a time ? it would be really helpful to me .

Comment: As long as the form is multi-part, then additional input type='file' with different names  should allow them to be retrieved through multiple xdmp:get-request-field() calls referencing the different form field names.

Comment: @DavidEnnis :  I already achieved to read the multiple content file at a time .Unfortunately   when i retrieve , with get request field i can get the 5 XML files data in single request field. How ever my intention is to store each  XML file individually in local file system  directory. so I am using xdmp:save to store my files. Now on what basis i can separate the content of each individual xml from a variable . so that i can create a new xml file and save it on local directory. are there any functions to separate content data ?

Comment: Hi. It appears to me that the original question was answered - xdmp:get-request-field().  You will probably get better help on your new inquiry by (1) accepting the answer above as acceptable for your original question and (2) opening a new question related to the XML question.

Comment: Thanks @DavidEnnis It's really helpful to me . I will open a new form and ask that question .